# How to display index based on value?

Tags: python-2.7

This is my code example:

```
budi = {"Name" : "Budi", "Gender" : "Male", "Age" : 18}
ahmad = {"Name" : "Ahmad", "Gender" : "Male", "Age" : 7}
ika = {"Name" : "Ika", "Gender" : "Female", "Age" : 18}

marged = [budi, ahmad, ika]
```

I want the results like this, for example based on the 18 year old:

```
The oldest participants are: Budi and Ika
```

Comment: What have you tried youreself?

Comment: you could have played more with Python...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code according to what have you asked in the question. Please go through this very simple implementation.

```
from operator import itemgetter

budi = {"Name" : "Budi", "Gender" : "Male", "Age" : 1}
ahmad = {"Name" : "Ahmad", "Gender" : "Male", "Age" : 7}
ika = {"Name" : "Ika", "Gender" : "Female", "Age" : 18}

marged = [budi, ahmad, ika]

newlist = sorted(marged, key=itemgetter('Age'), reverse=True)

maxAge = newlist[0]["Age"]
finalList = [newlist[0]["Name"]]
for person in newlist[1:]:
    if person["Age"] == maxAge:
        finalList.append(person["Name"])

if len(finalList) == 1:
    print "The oldest participant is: " + finalList[0]
else:
    print "The oldest participants are: ",
    for name in finalList:
        print name+" ",
```